# jq: count nest object values based on group by

Tags: json, jq

Json:

```
    [
  {
  "account": "1",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "2.01"
      }
   ]
  },
  {
  "account": "2",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "2.25"
      }
   ]
  },
  {
  "account": "1",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "15"
      }
   ]
  },
  {
  "anotheraccount": "a",
  "cost": [
      {
         "usage":"low",
         "totalcost": "2"
      }
   ]
  }
]
```

Results expected:

```
account cost
1       17.01
2       2.25
anotheraccount cost
a              2
```

I am able to pull out data but not sure how to aggregate it.

```
jq '.[] | {account,cost : .cost[].totalcost}'
```

Is there a way to do this in using jq, so I get all types of accounts and costs associated with them?

Answer (score 1):

Two helper functions will help you get you to your destination:

```
def sigma( f ): reduce .[] as $o (null; . + ($o | f )) ;

def group( keyname ):
  map(select(has(keyname)))
  | group_by( .[keyname] )
  | map({(keyname) : .[0][keyname], 
          cost: sigma(.cost[].totalcost | tonumber) })
;
```

With these, the following invocations:

```
group("account"),
group("anotheraccount")
```

yield:

```
[{"account":"1","cost":17.009999999999998},{"account":"2","cost":2.25}]
[{"anotheraccount":"a","cost":2}]
```

You should be able to manage the final formating step in jq.

Comment: I was trying this in the command line, how can I run above? Sorry new to this and not understanding how to make above code work?

Comment: I would suggest using the -f command-line option.  Please see the jq documentation.

Comment: above code is in python? I tried it in python and getting error on first line def sigma as invalid syntax?

Comment: or is there a one-line solution using pipe in bash? something among the lines of jq '.[] | {account,cost : .cost[].totalcost}'

Comment: You asked for a jq solution, which is what I gave. (As I said before, please consult the jq documentation.)

Comment: If you work at it, you could specify the jq program as a single line on the command-line, but why go to the trouble?

Comment: I want to call the api and then pipe it to return the results like above. I am not sure how I can do it with the solution provided above. That is why asking you for a command-line solution.

Comment: I tried this: q ' def sigma( f ): reduce .[] as $o (null; . + ($o | f )); ' | jq ' def group( account ): map(select(has(account))) | group_by( .[account] ) | map({(account) : .[0][account], cost: sigma(.cost[].totalcost | tonumber) }); ' - its not working? Can you please tell what am I doint wrong? It is not aggregating values?

Comment: Put all the lines in one file, say program.jq, and then invoke jq like this: jq -f program.jq